# How can I replicate the rollback from Entity Manager with JPA Repository?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am converting a project from Spring framework to Spring boot, so I am no longer using persistence files and other config files.

Also, I gave up using Entity Manager, instead I created repositories which extend JPA Repository, so that I can use the functions from there. The only thing is that I have some unit tests and in the Spring framework, at the end of each test there is a finally clause which has a rollback, so that the data from the database to be specific to each test.
How can I do that without Entity Manager? I tried using the flush() method, but no result...

Answer (score 0):

By default, data JPA tests are transactional and roll back at the end of each test.

You can refer to [Enabling and Disabling Transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx-enabling-transactions) in spring test documentation which indicate :

> Annotating a test method with @Transactional causes the test to be run within a transaction that is, by default, automatically rolled back after completion of the test. If a test class is annotated with @Transactional, each test method within that class hierarchy runs within a transaction. Test methods that are not annotated with @Transactional (at the class or method level) are not run within a transaction. Furthermore, tests that are annotated with @Transactional but have the propagation type set to NOT_SUPPORTED are not run within a transaction.

**Tips** :

- If you want to commit the transaction for a reason or another, you can use the `@Commit` annotation or less properly `@Rollback(false)` on method or class level.
- If you want to execute code outside of a transaction ( before or after ) you can use @BeforeTransaction and @AfterTransaction on public methods that have no return ( return void ) or on default method of interfaces.